# RegEx - Match only when a certain word occurs

Tags: regex

Its probably super simple.

I want to match only where a certain word exists in between full `<headers>`

This is what i have so far.

```
(<h[d{1-6}](.itemprop.)(.*?)</h[d{1-6}]>)
```

I want it to match

```
<h1 class="test" itemprop="name">Test</h1>
```

AND

```
<h2 itemprop="name" class="test">Test</h2>
```

AND

```
<h6 class="test"><strong itemprop="Price">9,99</strong>Test</h6>
```

As it is now it only matches `<h{1-6} itemprop` etc

Comment: Some good reading on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066

Comment: What's your dialect? `[d{1-6}]` is quite unusual.

Comment: i think this http://regex101.com/r/yM4iP6/1 is what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
<h([1-6]).*?\bitemprop\b.*?</h\1>)
```